# Laptop battery "extension" / external connect?

Tags: batteries, connector, lithium-ion, laptop

I have rebuilt an old laptop of mine that wasn't working and its chassis broken. In a nutshell after replacing the damaged components; I mounted the board and system on two acrylic sheets as shown in this picture:
[image: Laptop rebuilt on acrylic]

I am currently powering it using its power adapter connected to a UPS.
The only issue is its battery has no space in there and cannot be mounted easily. I am no expert in electrical matters, my question is can a laptop lithium-ion battery be connected external through some sort of "extension cord type" of connector? what components/connectors (or soldering?) should I be looking into?

PS: the laptop is an [Acer V3 – 571G](https://www.acer.com/us-en/support/product-support/Aspire_V3-571G) , and the battery is its stock one that came with it.

## Update

 uploading connectors pictures and size in mm as requested

**Battery with pins**
[image: battery with pins]

**Battery connector on board**
[image: battery connector on board]

**Battery with pins and size in centimeters (using ruler)**
[image: battery connector on board with size in cm]

**Battery connector on board with size in centimeters (using ruler)**
[image: battery with pins and size in cm]

Comment: Post pictures of the connectors, both on the battery and on the motherboard. Measure and report the exact pitch of the contacts in those connectors, in mm.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I attached photos with measurments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can a laptop lithium-ion battery be connected external through some sort of "extension cord type"

Yes, if you have a pair of corresponding mating connectors (one from a dead battery, and another from dead mainboard), you can make an extender of nearly any length, it is just wires. I have seen these extenders made by OEMs for their reference platforms and evaluation boards.

Comment: Thanks. Any reading material/how to videos you can refer me to? I am no expert in electrical matters

Comment: Would this do the job or potential hazard? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005687782928.html

Comment: @ccot, if you never did any soldering job, then it might be a challenge to you. Both connectors are meant for PCB through-hole mounting, and will take some skills to solder hanging wires reliably. Keep in mind that that power wires (+) and (-) must be bigger, AWG16-18 at least, and communication wires could be thin, AWG22-28. After soldering, you might want to secure the connection with a  blob of a good glue or epoxy.

Comment: Ok but will any 8 pin connectors work, or there should be specific ones for my laptop? like the ones in the link in my previous comment would work in our scenario? thanks for your time

Comment: @ccot , The connectors you show look right. If they fit your both ends, battery and mainboard, they should work.

Comment: ok thank you for the tips!